# Как оформляется такой (см.) диалог в подбор?

Tags: пунктуация

> Было смешно: Дима позвонил мне в Нью-Йорке и сказал: **«Приезжай ко
>   мне в гости», я говорю: «Не поеду, ты далеко живешь», он говорит:
>   «Приезжай, я тебе русских пельменей сварю и водки налью», я говорю:
>   «Ну, тогда ладно».** Мы так напились ужасно в тот день, а когда я
>   позвонила ему утром - узнать, не болит ли голова, его друг мне сказал:
>   «Знаешь, Дима занял 350 долларов, сел на самолёт и уехал в Россию». Он
>   был первой ласточкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да как угодно -  можно и так, можно разделить точкой, только слова автора разнообразить, заменить синонимами "он говорит", "я говорю":

*Было смешно. Дима позвонил мне в Нью-Йорке и сказал: «Приезжай ко мне в гости», я ответила: «Не поеду, ты далеко живешь», он настаивает: «Приезжай, я тебе русских пельменей сварю и водки налью», я сдалась: «Ну, тогда ладно».*

Comment: Люсенька, у  Вас всё очень красиво, но чуется мне, что автор так и хотел - нанизывать разные действия на один глагол! )))

Answer (score 1):

Наверно, есть какой-то особый смысл в том, что автор из раза в раз повторяет одни и те же "говорю"? (Мы этого не знаем.) Мне кажется, что для передачи диалога лучше разделить длинное предложение.
И еще: два двоеточия в первой части как-то не смотрятся. Может быть, лучше так:

**Ситуация была смешной. Дима позвонил мне в Нью-Йорке и сказал: «Приезжай ко мне в гости». Я говорю: «Не поеду, ты далеко живешь». Он говорит: «Приезжай, я тебе русских пельменей сварю и водки налью». Я говорю: «Ну, тогда ладно».**

Или так:
**Ситуация получилась смешной. Дима позвонил мне в Нью-Йорке и сказал: «Приезжай ко мне в гости»; я говорю: «Не поеду, ты далеко живешь». Он говорит: «Приезжай, я тебе русских пельменей сварю и водки налью»; я говорю: «Ну, тогда ладно».**